# redirect output, add text and append both to a txt file

Tags: bash

I'd like to log output of a program and a timestamp into a logfile. All of this will happen on a embedded system and the c-code of my program shall not generate timestamps.
Wht I'd like to have:

`[cat /proc/uptime] [printf output from program]`

All this happens in a wrapper so that all outputs of the program are logged.

Comment: Do you mean the wrapper script should catch the output of your program, put a timestamp in front of each line and write the output to stdout/a file ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you say yes to my comment, I created some simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read Line
do
  echo "$(cat /proc/uptime): ${Line}"
done
#
```

Store the code in a file, f.e. `wrapper` and give it execute bits `chmod +x wrapper`.
Now start it like: `<program> | wrapper`
or output to  file: `<program> | wrapper > logfile`
As long as your program generates output, the wrapper will catch it. If the program stops, wrapper will also.

Comment: I say yes. 
Your solution prints all outputs at (nearly) the same time to my logfile. I tested it with a c programm which outputs one line per second.
Same problem for my long-googling-solution:
`exec "${@:2}" | sed "s/^/$(cat /proc/uptime) /">> stupid.log 
# Problem here: the uptime is the same for all lines written
`

Comment: @Stefatronik, the script works as it is expected - [click here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26020559/).

Comment: @Stefatronik, if your program outputs very fast, you need to find a way to display the time in milli- or even microseconds ?

Comment: @WillemK no, this won't be so fast.

Comment: @pa4080: this is what I was looking for. Thanks your example how to use read and merge the string in echo.

Comment: @Stefatronik, here are more correct examples: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26020629/ ... I haven update the link yesterday. Maybe Willem could include these examples in his answer to make it acceptable.

Comment: @pa4080: My answer to the question is based to what the OP initially wrote: `Wht I'd like to have:... etc`. Then he eyes your suggestion and then he wants that. Op top of that,  in another question he requests more functionality for the same wrapper. I am sorry but I don't feel obliged to keep an eye on both his questions and alter my answer because the OP changes the requirements or  he suddenly likes other comments or suggestions that are given.